# Boost.Asio on iPad: resolver fails on a "fresh" 3G connection

Tags: ipad, boost-asio, resolver

I'm using Boost.Asio (Boost 1.46) on iOS(4.3), and I've got the following issue.

When trying to resolve a host name just after 3G connection is established (eg., switch "airplane mode" off and on), I get the following error: "Host not found (authoritative)".
The query looks like this:
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), "my.host.com", "9988");

On the other hand, if prior to the above query I open the browser or some other application that connect to the Internet, then the query works correctly.
Moreover, it seems that if I try the above query several times, it succeedes after a while.

Another interesting point: all the above occurs with 3G connection only, while with WiFi everything works well. And we couldn't reproduce this on iPhone.

What's could be the reason of such a weird behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that the iPhone has a barrier in place that makes this seamless, but the iPad doesn't (yet). As a work around, I'd start hunting for a prerequisite that you need to check before you perform network IO. I'm about to tread in to these waters, so please post your findings.